# Error overriding peer dependency - npm install reactstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, reactstrap

```
"@popperjs/core": "^2.6.0",
"@testing-/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
"@testing-/react": "^11.2.3",
"@testing-/user-event": "^12.6.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",
"react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
```

versions of dependencies I have in package.json file.

G:\Projects\React\confusion> npm install --save reactstrap

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"*" from @testing-/react@11.2.3

npm WARN   node_modules/@testing-/react

npm WARN     @testing-/react@"^11.2.3" from the root project

npm WARN   3 more (react-dom, the root project, reactstrap)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-popper@1.3.7

npm WARN node_modules/react-popper

npm WARN   react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactstrap@8.9.0

npm WARN   node_modules/reactstrap

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-/react@11.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-/react
npm ERR!     @testing-/react@"^11.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-/react@11.2.3

npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-/react

npm ERR!       @testing-/react@"^11.2.3" from the root project

npm ERR!     react-dom@"^17.0.1" from the root project

npm ERR!     1 more (reactstrap)

npm ERR!   2 more (the root project, reactstrap)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from create-react-context@0.3.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react-popper/node_modules/create-react-context

npm ERR!   create-react-context@"^0.3.0" from react-popper@1.3.7

npm ERR!   node_modules/react-popper

npm ERR!     node_modules/reactstrap

npm ERR!       reactstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Answer (score 20):

This is because of a change in npm version 7. See the [breaking changes section here](https://github.blog/2020-10-13-presenting-v7-0-0-of-the-npm-cli/). You can fix it by using the flag the error tells you to use at the bottom: `npm i reactstrap --legacy-peer-deps`. If one of your other dependencies already has reactstrap as a peer dependency, you might not need to install it at all (you can check with `npm ls reactstrap`), due to the change in v7.

Answer (score 13):

Try something like this in your `package.json`

```
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=8.7.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react": "$react"
  }
```

This will force react to be the version defined in your `"dependencies"` for all dependencies (& deps of deps).
You need "recent" npm as it was buggy in some version (I had 8.3.0 and overrides wasn't working). 8.7.0 seems ok !

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Comment: `npm ERR! Unable to resolve reference $react`

Comment: Double check your NPM version.

Comment: Using latest version of npm 8.19.1 and still getting `npm ERR! Unable to resolve reference $react` i have double checked that react exists on dependencies but still the same error .

Comment: I am not sure why, but in some project I explicitly mentioned the version instead of using ${package}....

Answer (score 10):

There is **2 ways** to fix this.

##### *Method 1:*

You can specify ***`--legacy-peer-deps`*** flag when you install a new package.

```bash
# For NPM
npm install package_name --legacy-peer-deps

#For Yarn
yarn add package_name --legacy-peer-deps
```

##### *Method 2:*

If you dont want to specify the ***`--legacy-peer-deps`*** flag everytime when you install a new package for the project.

You can simply create a file at the root directory of your project. The file name will be ***`.npmrc`*** (For NPM) or ***`.yarnrc`*** (For Yarn). Update the file with this:

***For `.npmrc`:***

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

***For `.yarnrc`:***

```
npmClientArgs: "--legacy-peer-deps"
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Method is worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

to install write this command in your terminal

step 1) if you're using npm

npm install your_package_name --legacy-peer-deps

step 2) if you're using yarn

yarn add your_package_name --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Delete node modules,
then `npm i reactstrap --legacy-peer-deps`
then `npm install  --force`
solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

To install any dependency forcefully run the below command:
npm i  --force
this command install the package forcefully without giving any error.

Answer (score -7):

To resolve REACT_SPRING installation issue try

```
npm install  --force
```

then

```
npm audit fix --force
```